# Como popular um JSonObject na mão?

Tags: android, json

Estou tentando mas não da certo, eu queria colocar ele na mão criado, como se eu já tivesse recebido meu arquivo JSON. Tentei colocar a estrutura do JSON dentro do JSonObject mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você que passar sua String no formato JSON para seu objeto JSONObject, você pode pode fazer algo assim:

```
try {
    String stringJSON = "{interests : [{interestKey:Dogs}, {interestKey:Cats}]}";
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(stringJSON);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    JSONArray array = obj.getJSONArray("interests");
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        list.add(array.getJSONObject(i).getString("interestKey"));
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Fonte: [Parsing JSON Object in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5015844/2290538)